# How to use brewperl for installing applications on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, perl, console, rxvt

I am use `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS` with `Perl 5 (v5.18.2)`, but for new versions of `rxvt` and `surf` I need `Perl v5.20+`.

As solution I found perlbrew and install `Perl v5.20`, found .deb with rxvt, but anyway cannot install, because it use system Perl.

My question is how to install applications on Linux with Perl dependency and do not break internal compatibility of Linux Core?

Comment: But rxvt and surf is not Perl modules, it's apps from repos. And when I try to dpkg -i this apps I cant, because they use system Perl 5.18 :(

Answer (score 2):

> *for new versions of `rxvt` and `surf` I need Perl v5.20+.*

That's not true.

`rxvt` 2.7.10 uses [a Perl script](http://sourceforge.net/p/rxvt/code/HEAD/tree/tags/rxvt-2-7-10/W11/wrap/mkproxy.pl) will work even with 15 year-old 5.6.

`surf` 1.0.6 doesn't use Perl at all (assuming you mean [this project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/surf/)).

Were you to try to install these from source, it wouldn't matter at all what Perl you had available.

Instead, you appear to be trying to install packages built for a system other than yours. To install *the `rxvt` and `surf` packages you have*, you need to have version 5.20 of *the distributor's `perl` package*. No matter how many version of `perl` you install, you'll never satisfy that requirement.

You can't install those packages. You'll need packages appropriate for your system, or you'll need to install the libraries from source.